# Can we append a dynamic value to v-if condition

Tags: vue.js

Based on the index value need the if condition to dynamically change and show the contents based on that.
Have 3 dropdown and when a certain value is selected from the drop down the 4 text fields need to be shown.
When I select a value from the first dropdown and meets the v-if condition then the 4 text fields are shown and when I go and select another option from the dropdown which also meets the if criteria the text fields are shown under the 2nd dropdown but fields under the 1st dropdown goes off.

```html
<template>
  <tr
    v-if="(rowIndex == index && isCtlRail)"
    :id="'ctlRail_'+items.id"
    style="line-height:2em;"
  >
    <td
      style="text-align:left; vertical-align:top;font-size:9pt;"
      colspan="4"
    >
      Length:
      <br>
      Left Cut:
      <br>
      Right Cut:
      <br>
      Rotate 90°:
      <br>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input
        id="bap_productLen"
        v-model="length"
        type="number"
        inputmode="numeric"
        value="20"
        maxlength="4"
        min="20"
        max="5000"
      >
      <br>
      <select
        id="leftCut"
        v-model="leftCutSelected"
        name="leftCut"
        style="font-size:10pt;"
      >
        <option value="45">
          45°
        </option>
        <option value="90">
          90°
        </option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <select
        id="rightCut"
        v-model="rightCutSelected"
        name="rightCut"
        style="font-size:10pt;"
      >
        <option value="45">
          45°
        </option>
        <option value="90">
          90°
        </option>
        <option value="135">
          135°
        </option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <input
        v-model="rotate"
        type="checkbox"
        :disabled="!rotateFlag"
      >
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

The above is the code for the 4 text fields to be shown. In the v-if condition , isCtlRail I am setting it as true when the index is 0 or 1 or 2 based on the condition check in the method. Similarly for rowIndex as well.

Tried setting dynamic value to if but condition did not work.
For eg:-
**v-if="(rowIndex_+index == index && isCtlRail_+index == index)"**
so that it will be specific to that particular row but did not work , always the text fields where shown under all the 3 dropdowns.

Please let me know how to proceed further.

Below is the method where I am setting the values for rowIndex
readOrdAttribute : function(value) {
console.log("Inside the readOrdAttribute function");
if(this.orderingAttribute !== undefined  && this.orderingAttribute.isCTLCable === 'true')
this.isCtlCable = true;
else
this.isCtlCable = false;
if(this.orderingAttribute !== undefined  && this.orderingAttribute.isCTLRail === 'true'){
//this.isCtlRail = true;
console.log("the ctrail shape is...rectangular...." + this.orderingAttribute.rail_shape);
this.railShape = this.orderingAttribute.rail_shape;
if (value === 'showDiv_1'){
//this.isCtlRail_0 = true;
this.isCtlRail_0 = '0';
this.rowIndex = '0';
this.rowIndex_0 = '0';
this.isCtlRail = true;
}
else if (value === 'showDiv_2'){

```
            //this.isCtlRail_1 = true;
            this.isCtlRail_1 = '1';
            this.rowIndex = '1';
            this.rowIndex_1 = '1';
            this.isCtlRail = true;
            console.log("value of isCtlRail_1 is " + this.isCtlRail_1 +"and rowIndex_1 is " +this.rowIndex_1);
            }
             else {
          
            //this.isCtlRail_2 = true;
            this.isCtlRail_2 = '2';
            this.rowIndex = '2';
            this.rowIndex_2 = '2';
            this.isCtlRail = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            if (value === 'showDiv_1'){
            console.log("value === 'showDiv_1'");
            this.isCtlRail_0 = '';
            this.rowIndex_0 = '';
            }
            else if (value === 'showDiv_2'){
                console.log("value === 'showDiv_2'");
            this.isCtlRail_1 = '';
            this.rowIndex_1 = '';
            }
             else {
                console.log("value === 'showDiv_3'");
            this.isCtlRail_2 = '';
            this.rowIndex_2 = '';
            }
        }
            
    },
```

Comment: First, show the variables with `{{ rowIndex }}` and make sure they are dynamic

Comment: I have added the method where the rowIndex is set. I am trying to show dynamic values with v-if condition but it is not working